# issues of shader graph and materials

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a custom shader graph and a Material that uses it. All of the Materials are stored in a Resource, and I am loading them at runtime and assigning them to the Renderer. However, not all of the Materials that I have loaded are displaying correctly.
I hope your help.

I thought it is because of directory of textures. but not well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All of the Materials are stored in a Resource

Are you referrring to the "Resources" folder? If so, make sure you named the folder exactly "Resources" and then you can use `Material material = Resources.Load("*materialname*.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;`.

If the materials are in a folder inside the Resources folder, you can just do
`Material material = Resources.Load("*foldername*/*materialname*.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;`.

Make sure you give as many information as possible! People are going to give you blind advices to your problem if you don't .